# Maven jUnit5 org.junit.platform.runner, org.junit.platform.suite.api does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit5

Using Eclipse.
Able to launch tests from Eclipse IDE, however 'maven install' fails and throws:

```
package org.junit.platform.runner does not exist
package org.junit.platform.suite.api does not exist
package org.junit.runner does not exist
cannot find symbol  symbol: class RunWith
cannot find symbol  symbol: class SelectClasses
```

these are are my pom.xml file dependancies

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Why my IDE is able to launch both test scripts and program itself, but maven build fails throwing the errors above?

Comment: Show your project structure.

Comment: used maven-archetype-quickstart artifact to init the project. Here is structure:
https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like I missed a couple of dependencies (had to add junit-platform-launcher and junit-platform-runner), also in order for tests to run on each build had to add build plugins. Now my pom.xml looks like this :

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

        <junit.jupiter.version>5.5.2</junit.jupiter.version>
        <junit.platform.version>1.5.2</junit.platform.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-runner -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-launcher -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 3):

surfire plugin will solve your problem. just add below in your pom before ending the project tag. once you add the dependency, you can run on command line "mvn test" or "mvn install"

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Jupiter with Maven only requires a single dependency as shown here: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/r5.5.2/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven

Comment: if I only add one junit-jupiter artifact I get the same error, which is described in the question. Maybe it's something with my IDE or project configuration, but the pom.xml configuration, which I posted in the answer solves the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to use the plain pom.xml in the project linked above? It works here. If it does for you as well, then my guess is that the failsafe plugin and the surefire plugin get in each other's way - or behave differently. Which target fails in your build?

Comment: Removed failsafe plugin and made pom.xml look the same as in that project, but still get the same error on build.
There are no profiles set in my pom.xml.
What is more I select pom.xml, right click on it in my IDE, then go to "Run As" and select "Maven Install".